# Inline JavaScript Markdown renderer does not reflect server-side C# limitations: can not stylize URL links

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

If you link to an answer with just a link it'll get expanded in the inline preview (as such the below is just `https://stackoverflow.com/q/28508017/124486` getting expanded to the title of the question),

- [How can you debug a process using gdb without pausing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28508017/124486)

However if you try to stylize it, such like this (which looks at least 9,000 times more professional)...

```
* _"https://stackoverflow.com/q/28508017/124486"_
```

As this,

- *"https://stackoverflow.com/q/28508017/124486"*

Then in the editor preview it will look kosher (just [[edit]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/379497/edit) this post to see what the in-line rendering displays), which means JavaScript is doing its job rendering the Markdown content properly.

The real problem here seems to be the server-side rendering with C#. When stylized, the URL is no longer expanded to the title of the question. I have reason to believe they're still on the shareware library version and that they'll have to upgrade it so the community can enjoy the enterprise level Markdown rendering we need.

### Can't edit the question with the link above to see it?

This is what it looks like in the editor preview:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I upvoted because of the discrepancy between the preview and the actual post, which is annoying (especially because there are many other such discrepancies). However the current example case of stylizing links does not seem all that useful to me, a link is already quite visibly distinct so there is no need to use different markup.

Comment: @Marijn it's not about making it known as a link. It's about setting it off from a paragraph. Normally, in English, you quote an article's name or the title of the post. It's awkward to just drop someone else's title in the middle of your sentence when you want to link to their post like [Why are titles in paragraphs not quoted this is silly](https://searx.org/). They should look more like, [_"Why are titles in paragraphs not quoted this is silly"_](https://searx.org/).

Comment: That is also my point, the fact that the link is shown in blue and underlined conveys the meaning of being quoted as a title. To put it differently, the reason for quoting and italics for titles that are not a link is to show where the title begins and ends, and to show that it is in fact a title and not some regular text. The normal link markup already does both those things.